# Reading conditional XML node Groovy

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I have below SOAP response:

I need to pick Address and nId having nIdType="ACTIVE" .

There could be more Address and nId and I need to pick the first match one.

I wrote groovy script and not got any success .please help me as I am new

There could be possible that all Address may or mayn't have nId

I have test property where I need to update both Address and nId

I need to implement through groovy script wh

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:GetD xmlns:ns2="http://xyxz/pqr" xmlns:ns3="http://pqp/ptr" xmlns:ns4="http://nhgg./ns">
            <ns2:du>
                <ns2:Address>UUUUUU</ns2:macAddress>
            </ns2:du>
            <ns2:du>
                <ns2:Address>XXXXXXX</ns2:macAddress>
            </ns2:du>
            <ns2:du>
                <ns2:Address>PQWWEEE</ns2:macAddress>
            <ns2:dP>
                <ns2:pN>1</ns2:pN>
                <ns2:sE>
                    <ns2:nId>08767727</ns2:nId>
                    <ns2:nIdType>ACTIVE</ns2:nIdType>
                <ns2:sE>
            </ns2:dP>
            </ns2:du>
            <ns2:du>
                <ns2:Address>TTTTTTTT</ns2:macAddress>
            </ns2:du>
        </ns2:GetD>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (I had to add a closing `</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>` tag to your XML and change `</ns2:macAddress>` to `</ns2:Address>` to make it valid XML)

```
def xml = '''<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            |  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
            |  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            |    <ns2:GetD xmlns:ns2="http://xyxz/pqr" xmlns:ns3="http://pqp/ptr" xmlns:ns4="http://nhgg./ns">
            |      <ns2:du>
            |        <ns2:Address>UUUUUU</ns2:Address>
            |      </ns2:du>
            |      <ns2:du>
            |        <ns2:Address>XXXXXXX</ns2:Address>
            |      </ns2:du>
            |      <ns2:du>
            |        <ns2:Address>PQWWEEE</ns2:Address>
            |        <ns2:dP>
            |          <ns2:pN>1</ns2:pN>
            |          <ns2:sE>
            |            <ns2:nId>08767727</ns2:nId>
            |            <ns2:nIdType>ACTIVE</ns2:nIdType>
            |          </ns2:sE>
            |        </ns2:dP>
            |      </ns2:du>
            |      <ns2:du>
            |        <ns2:Address>TTTTTTTT</ns2:Address>
            |      </ns2:du>
            |    </ns2:GetD>
            |  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            |</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'''.stripMargin()

def a = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ).Body?.GetD?.du?.find { node ->
  node.dP?.sE?.nIdType.text() == 'ACTIVE'
}

println "First Active Address = ${a?.Address?.text()}"
```

That prints:

```
First Active Address = PQWWEEE
```

But it's hard to tell from your question exactly what you're after

Comment: Thanks a lot ..I can't hardcode XML ,as that response is coming from a service which i dynamic in nature..   def response = context.expand( '${getD#Response}' ) can I use response  instead of your xml variable

Comment: @user1574409 Yes, you should be able to (assuming `response` is a String containing valid XML).  I just hardcoded it for the sake of a working example

Comment: Thank Tim ..it worked  and satisfy my requirement..on top the requiremnet  if I want to print all  active address having nIdType=="ACTIVE" what to do. shall I need to do findall instead of all and how to print all in loop or any other technique is there

Comment: Change `find` to `findAll` and then do `a?.each { println it.Address?.text() }`